# Request: Historical Street Atmos/Walla (Pre-50s)

Tags: historical, walla, atmosphere, street, vintage

I'm wondering if anyone has or knows where I could find Street Ambience or Walla from the first half of last century. I'm not concerned about a specific nationality or language.

I'm working on a uni project where the character travels to a unique, foreign land that has a vintage, steampunk style. The vehicles look vaguely like Model T Fords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your library for a WAV file named "old traffic". This is a cliche, very often used traffic sound that your uni might have on their drives. It's got a great little "beep beep" in the beginning of the file that I hear at least once a month in dated TV shows and movies.

Comment: And... in The Social Network :O? Big throw off for me. 

Comment: @Olle Yes!!! I've been saying that for years and no-one has really acknowledged the existence of the overuse of that file. Finally!!!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, walla sounds from the 50's don't sound all that different from regular walla's, when listening to the voices. What makes a great walla is not the individual voices, but the sum of it's parts. The thing that makes it sound specifically 50's are mostly contextual sounds, like the car honks that utopia refers to.
Focus on getting good 50s specific street sounds (incl. some voices by street vendors from that era) and everyone will believe it's the real deal/authentic.

Good luck on your project

Answer (score 0):

There might be a Fox 20th Century library of older sounds somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

There's this collection of sfx from the 50's to the 80's.  [http://sound-ideas.com/digivintage.html](http://sound-ideas.com/sfxmenu-vintage.html), also check this [link text](http://sound-ideas.com/sfxmenu-vintage.html)